# How to make request to amazon s3 using node js for downloading a file?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, amazon-s3

I made a request to amazon s3 using node js for downloading a file. In the response i receive the Buffer, here i have 2 problems:

1. If i send the buffer to frontend from node js like res.send(awsreq.Body.Buffer) and console log it once in node js and once in frontend, the buffer from frontend will look different than in node js.
   Node js Buffer: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 df a4 d2 6c 5a 01 00 00 20 05 00 00 13 00 08 02 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c 20 ... 11906 more bytes>
   Vue js frontend buffer: PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0 Show more(36,8kb)
2. How can i directly download the file from a request made from frontend? First how to receive that buffer corecly and how to convert it in that way frontend will download the file automatically? If possible how to do all of that in node js and when frontend receive the response to start automatically the download?

Comment: 1.) Don't really know about what you are doing
---
2.) For your second question have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Download a file from `amazon S3` follow these steps

1. Install aws sdk using this command `npm install aws-sdk`
2. Check below code

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: "ENDPOINT",
    accessKeyId: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    secretAccessKey: "YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
    region: "us-east-1",
    signatureVersion: "v4"
  })


const downloadParams = {
  Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
  Key: "KEY_NAME/FILE_NAME/FILE_PATH"
}

// Download the file
s3.getObject(downloadParams, function (error, fileData) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(fileData, "file")
  } else {
    
    console.log(error, " ERROR ")
  }
})
```

For more information you can check AWS official documentation using this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html

At last you can use
**Content-Disposition** in the request header

Or you can use pre Signed url

Example:

```js
const getpreSignedUrlForDownload = async () => {
  try {
  
    const parms = {
      Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
      Key: "FILE_KEY",
      Expires: 60 * 1,
      ResponseContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename"' + "FILE_NAME + '"'
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", parms, (err, url) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(url)
      })
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error)
  }
}

getpreSignedUrlForDownload()
```

Comment: after calling getSignedUrl, i receive an URL, that's right, but when i send that url to frontend/vue js it wont automatically download the file. How to set auto download the file if possible on node js, if not, in vue js/frontned?

Comment: It work for me. I am using the same code
Have you add 
ResponseContentDisposition properly??

Comment: I made a preview of that signed url, i dont need downloading the file anymore, but overall you were right, thanks